# a program to print even numbers of an array of numbers using (for…of) and using prompt -sync

Tags: javascript

```
let arr3 = require('prompt-sync')()('val')
let printevn = [];
function evennum(no) {
  for (eh of no) {
   if (eh % 2 == 0) {
      printevn.push(eh);
      continue;
    }
  }
}
evennum(arr3);
console.log(printevn);
```

When I don't take any value from user and lets say value are 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,12
my program prints even numbers  2,4,6,8,12 //no error

But when I use npm package known as prompt-sync which allows as to give user values from terminal itself same like prompt in web browser.

let's say the values are 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,12

my program prints 2,4,6,8,2 //**ERROR** it doesn't print 12 instead it prints 2 i.e 2nd digit of 12 [check the terminal output here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GqCzD.png)

Any suggestions please?

Comment: Are you sure that `arr3` is an array of numbers, not a string?

Comment: You would need to split the input by the delimiter (in this case, the comma) and trim each element, then convert the string into a number: `require("prompt-sync")()("val").split(",").map((t) => Number(t.trim()))`.

Comment: Are you sure the the input from the terminal is not a string? I'd try to use parseInt(input) for each number to see if that helps! String comparisons and number comparisons have very different results (especially with modulo)!

Answer (score 0):

```
let arr3 = require('prompt-sync')()('val')
let printevn = [];
function evennum(no) {
    // console.log(no)
    let arr = no.split(',').map(v => parseInt(v));
  for (eh of arr) {
   if (eh % 2 == 0) {
      printevn.push(eh);
      continue;
    }
  }
}
evennum(arr3);
console.log(printevn);
```

arr3 contains your input as a string.
You need to convert the comma-separated string to a number array, Then you can check if it is odd or even.